# MySQL: Modify column based on column values in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I've got two columns in the same table for my users: `name-displayed` and `short-name`.

`name-displayed` is populated with the full name of the user, for example "John Doe". In `short-name`, there is the short value, e.g. "john-doe" (essentially de-capitalized and hyphenated).

How would I amend the data in `short-name` based on the data in `name-displayed`? I'm sure I could use a self-join based on `UPDATE`, but I'm not sure how to implement a change in data across the columns.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Lower` and `Replace` functions for this.
See: [Lower](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) and [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in the docs.

```
Update <table_name> 
    set `short-name` = REPLACE(LOWER(`name-displayed`), ' ','-') 
    where <conditions>;
```

In case you want this done automatically, you'll need to write a trigger as Walter_Ritzel suggests.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER auto_set_short_name BEFORE INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`short-name` = REPLACE(LOWER(`name-displayed`), ' ','-');

END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks Nosh - creation of a trigger as per your syntax worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome; you may need to do it for `BEFORE UPDATE` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use triggers: [Triggers](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiopdnT173MAhUFGZAKHZW2DVAQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Ftrigger-syntax.html&usg=AFQjCNHj2JF0L2PSERatEbgVdbqVEFy1iQ&sig2=BboKED4pgK-H_zEVjCGKBA&bvm=bv.121070826,d.Y2Ia)

A trigger Before Insert/Update could solve that easily.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table
 FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
     SET New.`short-name` =  REPLACE(LOWER(NEW.`name-displayed`), ' ','-') ;
end;
//
```

Use backticks or this char: ```, to make sure the `-` is not interpreted as a minus sign.

Comment: Hey @Walter_Ritzel , since there are `-` characters in the table names you need to use backticks ` ` `

Answer (score -1):

```
update table a join table b on a.id = b.id
set a.short-name = b.name-displayed;
```

I understand you need to set name-displayed same as short-name,
if that is not the case
care to explain.
what you want to amend ??